# Inverse image of a Morse function is smooth

Tags: differential-geometry, morse-theory

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $f:M\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ a Morse function. Let $$M_a := \{p\in M\,|\,f(p)<a\}.$$ Then $\overline{M_a} = \{p\in M\,|\,f(p)\leq a\}$ and $\partial\overline{M_a} = \{p\in M\,|\,f(p) = a\} = f^{-1}(\{a\})$.

Is it true that $\overline{M_a}$ is a smooth manifold with smooth boundary $\partial\overline{M_a}$ if and only if $a$ is a regular value? How does one see this?

Comment: You want to look at two theorems: Implicit Function Theorem and Level-Set Theorem.

Comment: The interesting part is the only if. The other part is just the implicit function theorem. For the only if part you should look at local models of the critical point. The easiest way to see this is to use local homology at the critical point. First think of the 2 dimensional case.